# is there a way to force execute permission on all files that will be created under a specific directory?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

So I was wondering if there's a way to add in a way to force all files being created in e.g. /tmp/test directory to always have execute permission?

I tried via the setfacl, but that one doesn't allow files to have execute permissions, it allows directories though strangely enough...

Any other ideas? I can try and do the obvious of making a cronjob or script that loops and just adds those permissions in that directory, but that's a bit ham-fisted and rough.

Comment: Slightly less ham-fisted than a cronjob might be with `inotifywait` https://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywait

Answer (score 1):

The files cannot be given execution permissions by default as it can cause a security concern.

Other permissions can be set using `umask`:

> ```
>    umask [-p] [-S] [mode]
>          The user file-creation mask is set to mode.  If mode begins > with a digit, it is interpreted as an octal number; otherwise it is >interpreted as a symbolic mode mask
>          similar to that accepted by chmod(1).  If mode is omitted, the >current value of the mask is printed.  The -S option causes the mask to be >printed in symbolic form;
>          the  default output is an octal number.  If the -p option is >supplied, and mode is omitted, the output is in a form that may be reused as >input.  The return status
>          is 0 if the mode was successfully changed or if no mode >argument was supplied, and false otherwise.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to access (change to) a directory unless it is executable. Otherwise, a permission denied error will occur. I don't believe it is possible to make every file executable upon creation with setfacl.